# OLEDB Providers not found

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm getting the error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

I have a 64bit system with a 64bit application that have Office 2010 32bit installed. How can my 64bit application access OLEDB?

How can I list the available providers on the system?

Comment: is this using visual studio? if so, you can change the target CPU from 64 bit to 32.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407621.aspx

Comment: The build is not using VS and the app needs to stay 64bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can my 64bit application access OLEDB?

"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", that is, the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). There is a 64-bit version, too.

Connection strings for the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007).

> How can I list the available providers on the system?

Use [OleDbEnumerator.GetRootEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getrootenumerator):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {
   OleDbDataReader reader = OleDbEnumerator.GetRootEnumerator();

   DisplayData(reader);

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
   Console.ReadKey();
 }

 static void DisplayData(OleDbDataReader reader)
 {
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",
        reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
     }
     Console.WriteLine("==================================");
   }
 }
}
```